# Datetime field automatically converted to local (Can't Edit)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view) to learn a bit more about MvC4 but I'm having some problems with that `Datetime` field.

**First Problem**:
When I try to create an entry with a `datetime` in this format: `DD/MM/YYYY` (e.g. `20/06/2012`), I get an error:

> *The field ReleaseDate must be a date*

So I'm guessing it needs to be in this format (which is default in general): `MM/DD/YYYY` (e.g. `06/20/2012`).

When I use the second format, I get a message:

> *The value '06/20/2012' is not valid for ReleaseDate.*

The only way I can get it to work is when I enter both month and day <= 12. e.g. `12/12/2012`.

**Second Problem**:
This one is about the time. Let's say I enter `12/12/2012` and I get to successfully create an entry. By default it chooses `12:00:00 pm` as timestamp. The thing is that instead of pm it enters μμ (which is pm in Greek since clock in my pc is in Greek)

When I try to edit the entry I get an error because of that. If I change μμ to pm it accepts it. But its weird and kinda annoying to get an error from a valid entry without changing anything.

**Third Problem (Bonus)**:
I have a field that is a number. I enter for example `199` and it accepts it. But in my list it shows it as `199,00`. When I try to edit again and I click save, I get this error:

> *The field Price must be a number.*

If I delete the comma and the 00 it accepts it again..

As you can see its a very problematic table :) Any answers helping me out in any of my problems would be more than welcome.

Ideally I would like the datetime in this format: `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss` (without pm and am 24 hours)

But I will be happy for now if I can at least edit and save without the errors :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are important 3 things:

1. The format which is used when rendering the datetime field inside the form
2. The format which is used to validate the datetime field on the client
3. The format which is used to validate the datetime field on the server

Ideally those 3 formats must be the same. You mentioned that you are using the Greek Culture, so you could start by configuring this in your web.config:

```
<globalization culture="el-GR" uiCulture="el-GR"/>
```

At this stage the format for displaying the datetime field and validating the datetime field on the server will be `dd/MM/yyyy` because that's the format used by the el-GR culture.

The client side validation is another story. It is not influenced by your server configuration. It is influenced by the settings and the culture of the client browser. So even if you have configured your server to use `el-GR` to validate the datetimes if you have a client browser configured to use `en-US` culture then client validation will use the `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

Because client validation runs first (assuming you have enabled jquery unobtrusive validation), the en-US format will be used and even if the `20/06/2012` value is valid for your server side culture it is not valid for the client culture. In order to address this problem you need to use the [jquery.globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) plugin. So assuming you want to work with the `el-GR` culture here are the necessary scripts you need to add at the end of your HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts//globalize.culture.el-GR.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) ||
            !isNaN(Globalize.parseDate(value));
    }
    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) ||
            !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
    }

    Globalize.culture('el-GR');
</script>
```

Notice how the `date` and `number` methods of the `jquery.validate` plugins are overridden in order to use the `jquery.globalize` plugin when parsing those values.

Of course having so much scripts inside your page is not a good thing. In ASP.NET MVC 4 you could bundle them:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts")
        .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")
        .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
        .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
        .Include("~/Scripts/globalize.js")
        .Include("~/Scripts/globalize.culture.el-GR.js")
        .Include("~/Scripts/myscript.js")
);
```

where `myscript.js` will contain the overridden validation methods:

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||
        !isNaN(Globalize.parseDate(value));
}
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||
        !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
}
Globalize.culture('el-GR');
```

Now you could replace all those scripts from your Layout with a single bundle inclusion:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    ...

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
</body>
</html>
```

The last step is to address the format that is used when rendering the value of a datetime field inside an input field. When you use the `Html.EditorFor()` helper to generate an input field for the corresponding model property, this helper will use by default the current culture. So for example if you have a DateTime field and have set the culture to `el-GR` in your web.config the value will be rendered like so:

```
20/10/2012 12:21:22 μμ
```

If you want to remove the time part you could decorate your DateTime field on your view model with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute and specify a custom format to be used:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime SomeDateField { get; set; }
```

Remember that this specifies only the format used when rendering the value. Do not confuse with validation that I have addressed earlier.

Comment: Thx a lot for you detailed answer. I downloaded globalization.js and greek culture file and will try all this later when I got some more time. Will get back to you with feedback then!

Comment: I tried your solution and it partially worked. The displayformat attribute was really helpful. Now dates work like a charm in the format that i want. But I'm still having problems with the Decimal Number (Price). It continues to appear like (199,00) but when i try to edit and save it doesnt accept it. The only difference is now I dont get a message from validator and i think it has something to do with myscript.js that we used to override it. I probably did something wrong but im not sure what it is.